# Adobe Air for Android: Where is a xml file after instalation .apk file

Tags: android, xml, air, loading

An Air app which loading data from an external XML file (cfg.xml). I've published the Android/Air file, included the cfg.xml file in the Android package. Then I've installed on my  SD Card(). App's reading xml file - working perfectly. But I need raw access(on my device) to cfg.xml I cannot find this file, checked everywhere(Rooted Phone). Where is it? Is there other solution? I need a file which is easy to read/write.

Answer (score 0):

Use DDMS -> File Explorer and look for you app name in folders like data, ...

Comment: I believe the original poster is trying to leave you the following comment: *"I haven't got the rights to access data folder. Using adb shell ls /data //output: opendir failed, Permission denied. phone rooted"*

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Use fileStream instead of URLLoader
Change directory to SD Card e.g.

```
File.userDirectory.resolvePath("YourAppData/cfg.xml")
```

(No rooted phone needed)